# Should a teacher be educated?

Tags: banished

What effect (if any) does the teacher of a school being educated or not have?

Will it slow the education rate? I know students typically become educated workers at the age of 17, but sometimes when travel distance is extremely far they won't become an educated worker 'till 18+. Will something similar happen?

Comment: I do not see how this question belongs in the Video Games website

Comment: Banished the city-builder, has a School building, which requires a teacher. A teacher can be educated or uneducated. It is a valid question.

Comment: I am sorry, I did look up banished directly after commenting and I must've forgotten to delete the comment because I have never heard of banished until now

Comment: @Jaketr00 Question titles that are absurd without context are something of a tradition here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I know the teachers education has no effect on the students.

But I could observe a correlation between time spent in school by students and how fast they advance to educated workers, which also correlates with your travel distance experience.

This observation is also shared by others as noted in [this steam forums discussion](http://steamcommunity.com/app/242920/discussions/0/540734423811595844).